# NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array

Tags: ios, ios6, nsarray

Well, I know the cause of the error, my question here is how to avoid this kind of error. In my case, what I want is, if the user enters a wrong id which means when the array return 0 results, is says for example :

```
NSLog (@"The id you entered is false !");
```

else, it proceeds the code normally without crashing.

Any ideas on how I can solve it ?

Comment: a bit hard to 'help' you if you don't even show us the crashing code :))

Comment: you still don't show where you access the array

Comment: it access to the array which is inside the link using :
`NSDictionary *routes = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"routes"][0];`

Comment: I have answered here..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641051/ios-error-nsarrayi-objectatindex-index-1-beyond-bounds-0-0/30916210#30916210

May be helpful for someone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IOS App crash: \[\_\_NSArrayI objectAtIndex:\]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27243024/ios-app-crash-nsarrayi-objectatindex-index-0-beyond-bounds-for-empty-arra)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
id array = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"routes"];
if([array count] == 0) {
    NSLog(@"don't access it as the index is out of bounds);
    return;
}
```

Comment: that effectively negates a out-of-bounds exception :D

Comment: it gives an error saying that : ordered comparaison between pointer and NSInteger (aka unsigned int) and char *(*)(const char *,int)

Comment: as I said: without showing your code we can't 'help' you

Comment: try that ;) it looks like "routes" is your array and the index is 0 for you

Comment: it says gives an error saying that : `property 'count' not found on an object of type '__strong id'`

Comment: friendly advice: read some more about the language. edited it to use brackets

Comment: Di you make it by purpose? :) `Comparison of unsigned expression >= 0 is always true`

Comment: it was a variable earlier. I made a copy & paste error when I changed it. of course it is totally useless